# Accept array in query parameter for Joi.array().items(Joi.string())

Tags: node.js, joi

I want to accept array in query parameter, but quama separated array in query parameters are converted to string and I receive error
`"Error validating request query. \"status\" must be an array."`

Input request:
`http://localhost:3000/api/test?status=abc,xyz`

Error:
`{"body":"Error validating request query. \"status\" must be an array.","level":"info","message":"HTTP GET /api/test?status=abc,xyz","req":{"headers":{"accept":"*/*","acc ept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","connection":"keep-alive","host":"localhost:3000","user-agent":"PostmanRuntime/7.26.8"},"query":{"status":"abc,xyz"}},"responseTime":0}`

Schema for request validation:
`testSchema = Joi.object({ Joi.array().items(Joi.string()) })`

Router configuration
`router.get('/', validator.query(schema.testSchema), controller.getItems)`